# synchronizing java threads from a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Here is a contrived scenario of the problem I'm trying to solve.

**Input data: jigsaw puzzles**

- Puzzles could contain 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000 pieces
- You can be given more than one 1 puzzle as input

**Engine: jigsaw puzzle solver**

- Assembles the jigsaw puzzle (obviously the number of pieces is proportional to time)

**Output: assembled jigsaw puzzle**

- ***Requirement***: assembled puzzle must come out the same way it came in. for example, if P1 (1000 pieces) and P2 (10 pieces) came in as input, the output must be P1 then P2.

I’ve threaded the engine to use a thread pool to assemble the puzzles so I can process many puzzles at a time. However, in the example above, P2 will be solved before P1, but I need to mux the output together to ensure that P1 goes before P2. This, of course is a simplified example as I would expect to continuously be getting input data fed to the engine (I currently have a default of 10 threads) so the threads will be kept busy, but I still need to ensure the output order regardless of thousands of puzzles coming in.

What is a good way to ensure I can use my threaded engine and still produce the proper output?

Comment: [ExecutorService.invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) will return a List of Futures in the same order as the Callables given to it, after executing those Callables as simultaneously as the ExecutorService allows.

Comment: while I agree that would work, the issue here is that if 11 puzzles came in as input, the 11th one would not start processing until **all** ten puzzles have _finished_ processing

Comment: [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) might work. I will try it out...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Thread pools created with [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) or [Executors.newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) will execute many tasks simultaneously.